# Function from dom to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, show-hide

This is old version

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(id){
if (document.getElementById){
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "none"){
obj.style.display = "";
} else {
obj.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span onclick="showhide('1'); return(false);">show/hide 1</span>
<span onclick="showhide('2'); return(false);">show/hide 2</span>
<div id="1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
somthing here 1
</div>

<div id="2" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
somthing here 2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But now i wanna do this with jquery, here is example http://jsfiddle.net/AE75v/ or code

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#1").click(function() {
        if($("#1_1").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
        } else {
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
        }
        $("#1_1").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="1">Show 1 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="1_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 1 here</div>

<p>

<a id="2">Show 2 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="2_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 2 here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how to do it work with **onclick**, if onclick="**ID**" the same ID in `<div id="ID">` SHOW/HIDE...

all of this because i don't wanna all the time change the jquery code by addidng #ID and #ID_1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the ids to classes like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myLink").click(function() {
    var myLink = $(this),
      myContainer = myLink.next(".myContainer");
    if (myContainer.is(":visible")) {
      myLink.find('span').html('&#x25B2;');
    } else {
      myLink.find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
    }
    myContainer.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="myLink">Show 1 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div class="myContainer" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 1 here</div>

<br />

<a class="myLink">Show 2 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div class="myContainer" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 2 here</div>
```

This solution depends on the criteria, that the corresponding containers (div.myContainer) follows the links (a.myLink).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Add a class toggle to the anchor elements-->
<a class="toggle">Show 1 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="1_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 1 here</div>
<p></p>
<a class="toggle">Show 2 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="2_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 2 here</div>
```

then

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function(){
    //click handler to toggle element
    $('.toggle').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //toggle the display of next element
        $(this).next().toggle()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rC4L5/)

Comment: Arun sir ,you are great Coder,I see you daily here posting great ans.

Answer (score 0):

here fixed solution at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AE75v/2/

```
<div class="holder"><a id="1" class="link">Show 1 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="1_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 1 here</div>
</div>
<p>
  <div class="holder">  
<a id="2" class="link">Show 2 <span>&#x25B2;</span></a>
<div id="2_1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">Some text 2 here</div>
      </div>
```

And JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".link").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('div').slideToggle();
});
});
```